# how to change output location for each loop and run multiple loops

Tags: vba, excel

I have code here which loops through a list of files; opening them, extracting data and moving it into the main workbook. What i am looking to do get it so the data for abel is in columns c and d but then put varo in f and g etc. the problem that i see is that the placement code is inside the loop so for each i it will just write over the previous line instead of being in a different column all together!

```
Sub Source_Data()

Dim r
Dim findValues() As String
Dim Wrbk As Workbook
Dim This As Workbook
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim i
Dim tmp
Dim counter
Dim c As Range
Dim firstAddress
Dim rng As Range

ReDim findValues(1 To 3)
findValues(1) = "abel"
findValues(2) = "varo"
findValues(3) = "Tiger"

counter = 0

r = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
Set rng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(r, 1))
Set This = ThisWorkbook

For Each tmp In rng
    Workbooks.Open tmp
    Set Wrbk = ActiveWorkbook
    Set sht = ActiveSheet
        For i = 1 To 3
            With sht.Range(Cells(1, 1), Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell))
            Set c = .Find(findValues(i), LookIn:=xlValues)
                If Not c Is Nothing Then
                    firstAddress = c.Offset(0, 2).Value
                    Do
                        This.Activate
                        tmp.Offset(0, 2).Value = tmp.Value
                        tmp.Offset(0, 3).Value = firstAddress
                        Set c = .FindNext(c)
                        counter = counter + 1
                    Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Value = firstAddress
                End If
            End With
        Wrbk.Activate
        Next
    Wrbk.Close
Next tmp
End Sub
```

**EDIT:**I know it can be done by adding a multiplier of "i" to the offset value but this makes things bigger than they need to be if i wish to search for 50 keywords

Comment: You need to add something to the column for example`tmp.Offset(0, 2+counter).Value= `

Comment: was just editing the post to say that as you wrote this Dave :) was just hoping that there could have been a simple way. In my actual document i might be taking 7 values of 50 keywords so it would get to 400 cells wide minimum :/ EDIT: wait, maths is wrong. it would be so much wider than that!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my answer, hope to help you, and as always, if you need an improvement, just tell me.

```
Sub Source_Data()
Dim r
Dim findValues() As String
Dim Wrbk As Workbook
Dim This As Workbook
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim i
Dim tmp
Dim counter
Dim c As Range
Dim firstAddress
Dim rng As Range
Dim ColNum 'the columns number var

ReDim findValues(1 To 3)
findValues(1) = "abel"
findValues(2) = "varo"
findValues(3) = "Tiger"

counter = 0

r = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
Set rng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(r, 1))
Set This = ThisWorkbook

For Each tmp In rng
    Workbooks.Open tmp
    Set Wrbk = ActiveWorkbook
    Set sht = ActiveSheet
        For i = 1 To 3
            With sht.Range(Cells(1, 1), Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell))
            Set c = .Find(findValues(i), LookIn:=xlValues)
                If Not c Is Nothing Then
                    firstAddress = c.Offset(0, 2).Value
                    Do
                        This.Activate
                        Select Case i 'Test var i (the value)
                            Case "abel" 'in case the value (that is a string) is equal to...
                                ColNum = 1 'set the var, with the number of the column you want
                            Case "varo" 'in case the value...
                                ColNum = 2 'Set the column...
                            Case "Tiger"
                                ColNum = 3
                            Case Else 'In case that the i var not match with anyvalue take this column number
                                ColNum = 20 'the garbage!
                        End Select

                        tmp.Offset(0, ColNum).Value = tmp.Value 'Put the value in the selected columns
                        tmp.Offset(0, ColNum + 1).Value = firstAddress 'and put the value to the next column of the
                                                                       'selected column
                        Set c = .FindNext(c)
                        counter = counter + 1
                    Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Value = firstAddress
                End If
            End With
        Wrbk.Activate
        Next
    Wrbk.Close
Next tmp
End Sub
```

Note: 
You need to set the `ColNum` var to the values that you need, put there the numbers of the columns you really need to store the value of `i` and the next line is to put the address of the `i` var

Answer (score 0):

You can just change these two lines:

```
tmp.Offset(0, 2).Value = tmp.Value
tmp.Offset(0, 3).Value = firstAddress
```

To this

```
tmp.Offset(0, 2 + (i-1)*2).Value = tmp.Value
tmp.Offset(0, 3 + (i-1)*2).Value = firstAddress
```